# Splitting of exact sequence of G-modules

Tags: modules, representation-theory, exact-sequence, galois-cohomology

Suppose we have an exact sequence of $G$(finite)-modules;

$$0\to A=B^G \to B \to C \to 0$$

where $A,B$ and $C$ are $p$-primary groups. If p does not divide the order of $G$, can I say that the above exact sequence will split?

Comment: The sequence doesn't even need to split as a sequence of abelian groups.

Comment: Sorry, the previous version was incomplete. I have modified my question. Now, I think we can get a G-map from $B$ to $A$ with the required properties.